# Исчезли подсказки и совместимость HTML в PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Искал в интернете инструкции и фишки PhpStorm, для улучшения производительности в работе. Увидел такую комбинацию `Alt+Enter`, там начал тикать что попало и в итоге пропала связь с `html` (как я понял) форматом файлов, теперь когда пишу разметку страницы пропали подсказки и показывают подсказки вообще какого-то языка программирования, `html` синтаксис не воспринимает.
Пожалуйста подскажите как решить проблему.

Comment: возможно поможет создать проект заново

Comment: @diraria Не помогает, пробовал

Comment: ещё одно не очень хорошее решение может заключаться в сбросе всех настроек PhpStorm к стандартным, путём удаления папки `~/PhpStorm2017.2`

Comment: @diraria тоже как вариант, но не желательно, попробую завтра проверить ответ от Лены

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже, вы случайно создали какой-то language injection, и теперь Ваш код обрабатывается не как HTML, а как код того языка, который Вы заинжектили. Откройте страничку **Settings | Editor | Language Injections** и отключите все инжекшены с **IDE** scope (все, которые не **Built-in**)